# Qt creator for Android + Gstreamer

Tags: android, c++, linux, qt, gstreamer

I am using Qt Creator with `Qt 5.9.1` for Android under a Linux 64 bit client and I'm trying to pull in `Gstreamer 1.12.2` for Android into the build. I am able to partially run the gstreamer code. It will run `gst_init` and pass, but `gst_parse_launch` fails without being able to find any plugins, I always receive the same warning during runtime/debug with the error pointing to the first plugin.  Example below.

> no element for "videotestsrc"

I assume my *.pro file is to blame, but I cannot find a solution that uses the *.mk files that `gstreamer` illustrates in their [documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/for-android-development.html).  Due to gradle usage, and my unfamiliarity with gradle, I am unable to find where to use the *.mk files.

My *.pro file includes the following for plugins, but I seem to be missing something that links them together.

```
GST_ROOT = /usr/local/share/gstreamer-1.0-android/x86

INCLUDEPATH += $$GST_ROOT/include \
$$GST_ROOT/include/glib-2.0 \
$$GST_ROOT/lib/glib-2.0/include \
$$GST_ROOT/lib/gstreamer-1.0/include \
$$GST_ROOT/include/gstreamer-1.0

LIBS += -L$$GST_ROOT/lib/gstreamer-1.0/static  -lgstvideo-1.0 -lgstaudio-1.0 -lgstcoreelements \
    -lgstudp -lgstrtp -lgstx264 -lgstlibav -lgstvideoparsersbad -lgstadder -lgstapp -lgstaudiorate \
    -lgstaudioresample -lgstgio -lgstpango -lgstrawparse -lgsttypefindfunctions -lgstvideorate \
    -lgstvideoscale -lgstvolume -lgstvideofilter -lgstsoup -lgstopensles \
    -lgstvideotestsrc -lgstplayback -lgstaudiotestsrc -lgstaudioconvert -lgstvideoconvert \
    -lgstinterleave -lgstautodetect -lgstandroidmedia -lgstphotography-1.0 -lgstopengl

LIBS += -L$$GST_ROOT/lib/ -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 \
    -lgstbase-1.0 -lgstrtsp-1.0 -lgstvideo-1.0 -lgnutls \
     -lintl -liconv -pthread  -lffi
```

C code sample for registering the plugins:

```
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(coreelements);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(videotestsrc);

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    GError *error;

    //init gstreamer
    gst_init (NULL, NULL);
    gst_init_check (NULL, NULL, &error);

    //to check in debug
    gboolean i = gst_is_initialized(); //returns 1

    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(coreelements);  //fails -> cannot find gst_plugin_coreelements_register();
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(videotestsrc);  //fails -> cannot find gst_plugin_videotestsrc_register();

    ...
```

Any help would be useful, thanks for your time.

Comment: If it cannot find that GStreamer plug-in then you cannot help it with your code. That plug-in is missing on the system. Switch to Linux console and run gst-inspect1.0 pluginName to verify. And how to install that plug-in on target device is a different issue.

Comment: My system has gstreamer 1.12.2 installed, and it does find the plugin properly (in the example, videotestsrc).  My understanding is that the gstreamer android build is completely separate from the system build though, please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: If the target console (?) shows videotestsrc installed then I am not sure what went wrong. Try to do the whole pipe-line with ! as separators and launch some video test then. And maybe `GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER` is not working like that. I never used it.

Answer (score 0):

your gstreamer plugin not added to android device. In you pro file in Libs just linked, but not added to android. Just add this for each plugin:

```
ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS += \
      /path/to/plugins/android/gstreamer/libgstcoreelements.so \
```